# Generate separate PDF from Sheets in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will generate separate PDF files for Selected Worksheets in a Workbook. I found this code on line, which works great, it puts all selected sheets in ONE PDF. I need to have each selected sheet as a separate PDF.

I am a beginner to VBA.

```
Sub PDFActiveSheet()

Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet
strTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm")

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

'create default name for savng file
strFile = strName & "_" & strTime & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

'use can enter name and
' select folder for file
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

'export to PDF if a folder was selected
If myFile <> "False" Then
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: does your code, place all selected sheets in a single pdf, because that is what the code I found does as well. I need them to be separate pdf's....

Comment: Then once you have this completed pdf, get a script to produce separated pdf's   - I found an applescript one that works a treat but some must exist for the "other" side... Or you can look on here as that type of question has been asked before..

Answer (score 0):

Separate sheets to separate PDF files

```
Sub ExportToPDFs()
' PDF Export Macro
' Change C:\Exports\ to your folder path where you need the diles saved
' Save Each Worksheet to a separate PDF file.

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Select
nm = ws.Name

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:="C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\" & nm & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I keep getting "Run Time Error 1004" document not saved.... when I run this code.

Comment: Did you change the path to your local HDD?  The code works fine for me.

Comment: Yup and it still doesnt work.. maybe my path is incorrect?

Comment: Just saying Run-Time error '1004'.. Method 'Select of Object'_'Worksheet' failed.

Comment: When I step through the code it saying that this line is bad: ws.select..

Comment: Well 'ws.Select' simply selects a worksheet.  I'm not sure what's going on over there.  I tested the code on my home machine; it worked fine.  I just tested it on my office machine; it works fine.  The only possible thing that I can think of is that this part: 'C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\' needs to be set to your local hard-drive.

Comment: I am running this code in a workbook that has about 12 sheets in it. When I select sheets, for example, sheet 3 and 4 and I run this marco only sheet 1 is being saved to PDF format (even though I did not select that sheet) and then I get an error "Method 'select of Object'_worksheet failed.